# Nodejs Put request throwing 400 Bad request Error

Tags: node.js

Hi I am new to Nodejs and trying to make a put request to an API and end up getting HTTP 400 bad request error. Not sure where I am making a mistake.

```
function doSwitch(token) {
    var formData = querystring.stringify({
        name: 'region1',
        host: 'host1'
    });
    var put_options = {
        host: 'api.enterprise.xxx.com',
        port: '443',
        path: '/v1/updatehost/',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(formData)
        },
    };
    var put_req = https.request(put_options, function (res) {
        if (res.statusCode != '200') {
            console.log(colors.red.bold("Error code :- " + res.statusCode));
            console.log(colors.red.bold("Error Message :- " + res.statusMessage));
            return;
        } else if (res.statusCode == '200') {
            console.log(colors.green.bold("API Switch Successful!! Error code :- " + res.statusCode));
        }
    });
    put_req.write(formData);
    put_req.end();
}
doSwitch(token);
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Do a console log of `res.statusCode`, what value do you get?

Comment: Hi @Joel this is the Error I get -- Error code :- 400
Error Message :- Bad Request . The same request with a CURL works fine.

Comment: This is kinda hard to diagnose since i don't have a working example to work with. Are you supposed to have a space after `'Bearer '` ?

Comment: Similar POST request  works fine.(with Space).

Comment: We get a 400 HTTP status code, when there's some problem with Headers, check  if you are filling headers correctly, just print them and check